# Defining an inside class in the IF statement

Tags: java, if-statement

I have a problem with referencing to an inside class that is defined in IF statement, in the method main of outside class. Here is my code:

```
public class Outside {
```

`int IntVar;
public void Condition() {
    if (IntVar == 0) {
        class Inside {
            public void f() {
                System.out.println("Inside : f ");
            }
        }
    }
    else IntArg = 5;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Outside object = new Outside();
    object.CreateAnInsideClassCondition();

}`

}

How to declare a new object of a class Inside and call out method "f" in main ? P.S. the code was bad but it is already changed

Comment: No, that is not valid Java, in more ways than one.

Comment: `public void Condition (IntVar == 0)`... what?

Comment: It should be  public void Condition { if (IntVar == 0) {...

Comment: Where is Edit or Delete button ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't define a member class based on a condition in your method. But you can use a delegate and a lambda or anonymous inner class like this:

```
public class Outside {

public Function<Object,Object> delegate = arg -> null;
int IntVar;
public Outside(int param){
  this.IntVar = param;
}
public void Condition() {
    if (IntVar == 0) {
        delegate = (arg) ->{ System.out.println("text"); return null; };
    }
    else IntArg = 5;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Outside object = new Outside(0);
    object.Condition();
    object.delegate.apply(null);
}
}
```

This code requires Java8, but you can do it with older ones, less conviniently, though. If you need more complex behavior from Inside.f(), you may want to replace lambda with anonymous inner class.
Also note, that you had no constructor for outside and messed with method names a little.